# Absolute link in PHP

Tags: html, http

In one of the module PHP file I want to change the URL anchor to another webpage. When I modify the href value to `href="www.redirected_page.com"` on my webpage it shows me this link: http://www.my_webpage.com/www.redirected_page.com.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

You need a protocol, or the browser will interpret the URL as relative. You must put `http://www.redirected_page.com` not `www.redirected_page.com`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `<a href="http://www.redirected_page.com">`, that usually does the trick.

The distinctive part between relative and absolute paths is that absolute paths have the protocol included (`http://` or `https://`) where relative paths do not.

Comment: my apologies. this was the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

That isn't even absolute.

Prepend the protocol `http://` to the url!

```
<a href = "http://www.my_webpage.com"> </a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AMHNG/